# Why does foreach allocate int arrays in C#?

Tags: c#

Why does [Rider DPA](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/2021.2/Fixing_Issues_Found_by_DPA.html) say that this code allocates int arrays?

[image]

Comment: Something likely allocated something. Since this is an enumerable, we cant see what where when or why. As to why Rider says something is allocated is beside the fact, who knows what rider does or how its tracking these things

Comment: What is being measured here? An `IEnumerable<int>` source can do *literally anything* when iterated; so: if it is measuring runtime cost, then: blame whatever you're passing in to this method. I could write an iterator block that allocates increasingly large arrays between each `yield return`, for no reason other than to be a nuisance.

Comment: Please show the way you invoke this code. I suspect it has to do with your `IEnumerable<int>` implementation "materializing" the sequence (i.e. there's a deferred execution that happens to hit inside the `foreach` loop).

Comment: In short the question is unanswerable in its current state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`foreach` doesn't *itself* allocate anything (except space for some locals, which aren't heap allocations in this case). It is roughly equivalent to:

```
int result = 0;
using (IEnumerator<int> iter = numbers.GetEnumerator()) {
    while (iter.MoveNext()) {
        var number = iter.Current;
        result |= 1 << (number - @base);
    }
}
return result;
```

As you can see: it has literally no direct allocations, *but* whatever you pass in as `numbers` has 4 opportunities to do anything it chooses: `GetEnumerator()`, `MoveNext()`, `Current`, and `Dispose()`. We can't tell you what the input `numbers` is, but there's a good chance that the tool is measuring these invisible allocations and attributing them to the `foreach`.

Look at whatever `numbers` is.